# Android head unit 8227L with no physical buttons bootloop

Tags: recovery-mode, boot-loop, android-auto

After successfully rooting Android head unit 8227L, I decided to update SuperSU binary files and unfortunately ended up with a boot loop. After many trials and errors, I eventually managed to open `Recovery Mode` but as my unit doesn't have physical buttons I'm not able to navigate it.

Connecting USB keyboard doesn't work. Long/short press reset button neither (it confirms `Reboot` option which is initially highlighted). I tried to `Wipe data/Factory reset` through ADB but anytime I enter ADB shell I receive an error:

```
exec '/system/bin/sh' failed: No such file or directory
```

How to navigate the recovery menu or deal with this error?

Comment: Unless you're on custom recovery, your only way out is flashing the full phone software or flashing in a custom recovery so that you can have advanced options like flashing the universal unroot script to remove the supersu and restore the stock permission management services

Comment: Any ideas how to navigate on recovery menu? This head unit doesn't have physical Vol+ nor Vol-

Comment: If the Stereo doesn't have a touch interface not have buttons. I think the best is reflashing it if it has a serial port and you have its cable. But if a touch interface resides. If you can get hands on a modern custom recovery like TWRP for the specific model, you can use it to perform tasks by touch

Comment: I tried to flash TWRP via adb but it requires enabled OEM. When I try to do it via command `fastboot OEM unlock`, fastboot asks me to authorise this action by pressing Vol+...

Comment: Your only solution. Get official firmware and flash with SP Flash Tool if its an MTK based device.

Comment: Sadly this device (although it was produced in china) is - let's say fully locked. Purposeful action of the local company in my country. Had no choice but to send it to their service and pay for simple things ;( money talks!

Comment: Nice then. Be glad an option is there

Comment: Anyway, thank you for your help ;)